# openmp pointers question

Tags: c, pointers, openmp

I have written a program in C which needs to be parallelised using openmp.
I have declared the private and shared variables but in the beginning of the code when I am calling some procedures to free up the lists I get

```
error for object 0x1000c1e20: pointer being freed was not allocated

      destroy_t_value(head_t1_values);
      t_value_delete(&head_t1_values, 0);
      destroy_chi_value(head_chi1_values);
      chi_value_delete(&head_chi1_values, 0);
```

These variables are private
The code works fine without openmp

Comment: we have not enough info to answer your question, where do these variables get initialized?

Comment: Before entering the parallel part they are allocated and set to NULL

Comment: it seems you are freeing a pointer that is not pointing to dynamically allocated memory

Comment: Yes but it was working fine before openmp

Comment: You say that you have declared the variables shared and private in the OpenMP region.  How are you declaring the pointers - shared or private?  If they are shared, could you be trying to deallocate them multiple times?  If private, then maybe you should be declaring them firstprivate.  Need to see more code on how you are using the variables before parallel region, within parallel region, and after parallel region.

Answer (score 2):

That is the problem: "Before entering the parallel part they are allocated and set to NULL"

You cannot allocate a pointer, then set it to NULL and then free it, cause now you are freeing a pointer that points to nothing.

You need to allocate, then use them, then deallocate (ie delete) and then set to NULL.

Comment: In the procedure that i am freeing the pointers i check if they are NULL. If they are I am not doing anything to them